# Normality of $\frac{G_{i}\cap N}{G_{i+1}\cap N}$ in $\frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}}$ related to a composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

**Question:**

Assume that$$G=G_0\supset ...\supset G_{i}\supset G_{i+1}\supset...\supset G_n=\{e\}$$ is a composition series for G,and $N$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$.

Prove that $$\frac{G_{i}\cap N}{G_{i+1}\cap N}\triangleleft\frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}}.$$

(in the sense that $\frac{G_{i}\cap N}{G_{i+1}\cap N}$ is the image of the injective homomorphism $\frac{G_{i}\cap N}{G_{i+1}\cap N}\to \frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}}).$

**Attempt:**

By applying the third isomorphism theorem we have $$\frac{G_i\cap N}{G_{i+1}\cap N}\triangleleft \frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}\cap N}$$

since $G_{i}\cap N\triangleleft G_i$.

But I have trouble showing that $\frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}\cap N}$ is a subgroup of $\frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}}$,since the inclusion failed to be a homomorphism(even not well-defined).

Comment: Surely it's not going to be a subgroup, your problem says (in a rather obscure way) that we're talking about the image under the natural injection etc etc. My hint would be: show that $x\mapsto xG_{i+1}$ is a homomorphism carrying $G_i\cap N$ to a *normal* subgroup of $G_i/G_{i+1}$ and then compute the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $G_i\cap N\triangleleft G_i$, since $N\triangleleft G$. Since $G_{i+1}\triangleleft G_i$ as well, we have $(G_i\cap N)G_{i+1}\triangleleft G_i$.

By the correspondence theorems we know that
$$\frac{(G_i\cap N)G_{i+1}}{G_{i+1}}\triangleleft \frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}}.$$

The Second Isomorphism Theorem tells us that if $M\triangleleft G$ and $K$ is any subgroup, then $\frac{K}{K\cap M}\cong \frac{KM}{M}$, via the map $k(K\cap M)\mapsto kM$.

Taking $M=G_{i+1}$ and $K=G_i\cap N$, we have
$$\frac{(G_i\cap N)G_{i+1}}{G_{i+1}} \cong \frac{G_i\cap N}{(G_i\cap N)\cap G_{i+1}}.$$
But $G_i\cap N\cap G_{i+1} = N\cap G_{i+1}$ (since $G_{i+1}\leq G_i$). Therefore, we have
$$\frac{G_i\cap N}{G_{i+1}\cap N} \cong \frac{(G_i\cap N)G_{i+1}}{G_{i+1}}\triangleleft \frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}},$$
where the isomorphism is the natural one, sending $g(G_{i+1}\cap N)$ to $gG_{i+1}$.